# Find all positive integer sequences that make this expression an integer.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that we have an infinite periodic sequence of positive integers $(x_i > 0)$ with a period of $n$ , $(n ≥ 1)$:

$$x_i=x_1,x_2,....,x_n,x_1,x_2,...$$
And let $S_i$ be the sum of the first $i$ elements in the sequence:
$$S_i = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + .... + x_i$$

Find all positive integer sequences , such that:

$$w = \sum_{ k = 0 }^{ n  -  1 } {( \frac{ 3  ^ {n-k-1} \times  2  ^ {S_k }}{ 2  ^ {S_n} -  3  ^ { n }} )} ∈ Z $$

Here are the solutions I found:
$x_i = 1,1,1,.... $

$S_i = 1,2,3,.... $

$w = 1 $

$$ $$
$x_i = 2,2,2,....$

$S_i = 2,4,6,....$

$w = -1$
$$ $$
$x_i = 1,2,1,2,.... $

$S_i = 1,3,4,6,7,9,....$

$w = -5$
$$ $$
$x_i = 2,1,2,1,.... $

$S_i = 2,3,5,6,8,9,....$

$w = -7$
$$ $$
I have been able to prove that those are the only solutions that exist for $ n = 1 , 2$

But, I haven't been able to find any new solutions for $n>2$

Note: sequences that are solutions for $n=h$ they're also a solution for $n=kh$ $(k≠0)$
For example :

$x_i = 1,2,1,2,.... $

$S_i = 1,3,4,6,7,9,....$

$w = -5$

It's a solution for $n=2,4,6,...,2k$ $(k≠0)$

Comment: 1/ For a given sequence, is $n$ fixed? If so, I'm not sure why you'd care about $x_{n+1}$, or why it needs to be periodic, since $x_{n+1}$ is not used anywhere.  2/ However, in your writeup, you didn't state which value of $n$ corresponds to those sequences. Does this hold for all $n$?

Comment: I made $x_i$ periodic to prevent having infinite number of solutions

Comment: 1/ To clarify, why can't you just have a sequence of $n$ terms? Why must the sequence be infinite? (I guess I get what you're trying to say, and this is just simplifying the phrasing so that others can focus on what's important.)  $\quad$ 2/ Please answer my question 2 above too. What $n$ are you working in?

Comment: It's hard to clarify what this question means, but it has to have a finite number of solutions, for example x_i = 1,2  , x_i = 1,2,1,2 and x_i = 1,2,1,2,1,2 if we supposed that n is finite and has n terms , they would be 3 separate solutions ,but actually they're exactly the same one ,and n ≥ 1